# Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : there is no package called ‘rio’

Tags: r, r-rio

there is no package called ‘rio’. Is there any package that contains it?

```
df <- scale(gemaps_88)     # Standardize the data
res.fanny <- fanny(df, 2)  # Compute fuzzy clustering with k = 2



df <- scale(c_matrix)     # Standardize the data
res.fanny <- fanny(df, 2)  
head(res.fanny$membership, 3) # Membership coefficients

res.fanny$coeff # Dunn's partition coefficient

head(res.fanny$clustering) # Observation groups

library(factoextra)
fviz_silhouette(res.fanny, palette = "jco",
                ggtheme = theme_minimal())
```

Comment: Just install it then?

Comment: `install.packages("rio")` ?